# mongodb ORing and ANDing query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-scala

I am using mongoDB database. in which I have collection in below format.

```
{ name : name1 , area: a , country : c}
{ name : name2 , area: b , country : c}
{ name : name3 , area: a1 , country : c1}
{ name : name4 , area: b1 , country : c1}
```

i want query like

```
select * from coll where (country =c and area =a) or (country = c1 and area = b1)
```

in mongodb query.

I have read many document but not found suitable answer.

So if any one knows please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all elements in a mongodb query use the `and` operator. You can specify an `or` operator using the `{ "$or": [ ... ] }` construct, as described in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries).

Your query will be :

```
{ "$or": [ { "country": "c", "area": "a" }, { "country": "c1", "area": "b1" } ] }
```